# Parsing issue in COUNT function of formula in xlwt

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlwt

I need to use a spreadsheet module to write and update a simple two-worksheet workbook every time I run some other script. Been testing some of the modules, gave up on `openpyxl` because of too many errors while running test code (such as not being able to format multi-line text values into a cell as column headers).

Now, trying `xlwt`, here's my test code:

```
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook, Formula

workbook_name = 'xlwt_test01.xls'
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet01 = book.add_sheet('DATA')
sheet02 = book.add_sheet('FORMULAE')
sheet01.write(0, 0, 'Hello\nWorld') # A1: no style, no wrap, despite newline
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.alignment.wrap = 1
sheet01.write(0, 1, 'Hello\nWorld', style) # B1: with style, there is wrap
sheet02.write(0, 0, 'count of rows\nin DATA worksheet', style)
sheet02.write(1, 0, Formula('COUNTA(DATA!A:A)'))
```

This fails as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlwt_test01.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-1.0.0-py2.7.egg\xlwt\ExcelFormula.py", line 22, in __init__
  raise ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException("can't parse formula " + s)
xlwt.ExcelFormulaParser.FormulaParseException: can't parse formula COUNTA(DATA!A:A)
```

The purpose of the formula on sheet 2 is to count all populated rows in sheet 1.

Does xlwt have problems with formulae?

Anybody see a coding error?

I can physically open the workbook and enter the same formula by hand into another cell (using the Excel = syntax of course) and it works fine.
I've downloaded the xlwt doc and read it but it's fairly light-weight, doesn't provide much info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that `xlwt` cannot parse the column range `A:A`.

You can either specify some smaller range that will work for you such as:

```
sheet02.write(1, 0, Formula('COUNTA(DATA!A1:A100)'))
```

Or specify the full column range explicitly:

```
sheet02.write(1, 0, Formula('COUNTA(DATA!A1:A65536)'))
```

When you open the file the full explicit range will be converted back to `COUNTA(DATA!A:A)`.